# Using post_class to style posts indivdually

Tags: css, post-class

I have a homepage on which I want to display the latest post different from the other posts. I haven't used `post_class` and I am not sure how to.

Would I be able to achieve what I want using `post_class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [`post_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) (and [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) for that matter) but you don't need it for this. Alter your Loop on your home page to conditionally format the first post.

```
$first = (!is_paged()) ? true : false;
if (have_posts()) {
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    if ($first) {
      // code to format the first post
      $first = false;
    } else {
      // code to format all the other posts
    }
  }
}
```

If all you need is a small change that can be made via CSS then you can pass `post_class` a parameter.

```
$first = (!is_paged()) ? 'is_first' : 'not_first';
if (have_posts()) {
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    echo '<div ',post_class($first),'>';
      // the rest of your Loop
    echo '</div>';
    $first = 'not_first';
  }
}
```

Comment: `post_class()` echos it return value. You could use [`get_post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_class) instead, but it comes with out the HTML tags `class` attribute.

Comment: @kaiser : Test the code. Note that that is a comma not a period. There is a peculiarity with `echo`. If you use a comma, strings are `echo`ed immediately, not concatenated which means that works perfectly well.

Comment: Oh, really? Didn't even know that. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @s_ha_dum that is exactly what i needed, thanks!. i have a custom design and i think its advance. where can i get more help material in customizing my layout?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually **very** simple: Use the `$wp_query` object property `current_post`. You have to note that it's starting the index with `0`, so I'm counting up by one in the example below.

```
if ( have_posts() )
{
    while( have_posts() )
    {
        the_post();
        ?>
        <article <?php post_class( "post-nr-{$GLOBALS['wp_query']->current_post+1}" ); ?>>
            <?php
            the_title();
            the_content();
            ?>
        </article>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use php code to do this.  It adds "hits" that are not that necessary.  CSS might be a better option for you e.g.

```
.post:nth-child(1) { ... }
```

or

```
.post:first-of-type { ... }
```

and let the browser do the heavy lifting of styling it up?  Just a thought.